# Save the loop output into csv file

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I want to save the loop result into a csv file or dataframe; the below code just writes the tweets to the console.

```
j =1 
sortedDF = tweets_df.sort_values(by = ['Polarity'])
for i in range (0, sortedDF.shape[0]):
    if(sortedDF['Analysis'][i] == 'Positive'):
        print(str(j)+')'+ sortedDF['transalted'][i])
        print()
        j = j+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("some.csv", "w") as f:
    j = 1
    sortedDF = tweets_df.sort_values(by=['Polarity'])
    for i in range(0, sortedDF.shape[0]):
        if (sortedDF['Analysis'][i] == 'Positive'):
            f.write(str(j) + ')' + sortedDF['transalted'][i])
            print()
            j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can call `writelines` at the end instead of `write` in for loop which is more optimized solution.

```
sortedDF = tweets_df.sort_values(by=['Polarity'])
file = open("positive_tweets.csv", "w")
lines = []
j = 1
for i in range(0, sortedDF.shape[0]):
    if (sortedDF['Analysis'][i] == 'Positive'):
        lines.append(str(j) + ')' + sortedDF['transalted'][i])
        j += 1
file.writelines(lines)
file.close()
```

Comment: Usman this code creates the file but shows an error. I am working in Google Colab, and the error is can't fetch the data from the backend, Can you please guide me, on what should I do?